# Python- text based game not calling the correct room

Tags: python, class, oop, namespaces, python-import

I am writing a text based game and I want to link each room to four other rooms- north, south, east and west. I am starting with just north for now. The user should be able to type 'walk north' and the north room should be called.

I have used three files- one where I will write the main story, one to call the appropriate room within the story and one for navigation to avoid mutual importing.

rooms.py:

```
import actions

class FirstRoom(object):

    room_name = 'FIRST ROOM'
    north = 'north_room'

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        print self.room_name
        while True:
            next = raw_input('> ')
            actions.walk(next, self.north)
            actions.command(next)


class North(object):

    room_name = "NORTH ROOM"

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        print self.room_name
```

actions.py:

```
import navigation

def walk(next, go_north):
    """Tests for 'walk' command and calls the appropriate room"""
    if next == 'walk north':
        navigation.rooms(go_north)
    else:
        pass
```

navigation.py:

```
import rooms
first_room = rooms.FirstRoom()
north_room = rooms.North()

def rooms(room):
    rooms = {
        'first_room': first_room.start(),
        'north_room': north_room.start(),
        }
    rooms[room]
```

When I run first_room.start() it should print 'FIRST ROOM' which it does. Then I type in 'walk north' and I expect it to print "NORTH ROOM", but instead it prints "FIRST ROOM" again.

I can't figure out for the life of me why it doesn't work the way I expect it to, it's as if it's calling first_room again instead of north_room. Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `rooms[room]` is a statement that will do nothing if you don't store it somewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that the issue occurs because of how the dictionary `rooms` is defined. When you do -

```
rooms = {
    'first_room': first_room.start(),
    'north_room': north_room.start(),
    }
rooms[room]
```

The functions get called when you define the dictionary itself, not when you access the values from it (so both functions get called) , you want to store function objects (without calling them) as the values and then call them as - `rooms[room]()` . Example -

```
def rooms(room):
    rooms = {
        'first_room': first_room.start,
        'north_room': north_room.start,
        }
    rooms[room]()
```